# UVC Extension Unit CoCreateInstance Failed

Tags: windows, com, usb, driver, directshow

I am trying to write an UVC extension unit driver for UVC compliant USB camera.

**Where do I start?**

I started the development based on MSDN sample provided in the following link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Replaced all the GUIDs as specified in the procedure. I am using Logitech Pro 9000 USB camera. Got UVC extension guid using UVCView tool and assigned for  PROPSETID_VIDCAP_EXTENSION_UNIT.

Wrote a sample application to access this extension unit.

```
IExtensionUnit * g_pIXCcontrol;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(IExtensionUnit), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
    IID_IExtensionUnit, (void **)&g_pIXCcontrol);
```

**What issue I face?**

CoCreateInstance returns **Class not registered HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)**.

I have registered uvcplgn.ax through command prompt with regsvr32 command, which in turn throws message as successfully registered. But even after registering, CoCreateInstance throws class not registered error.

What may be the reason for this? Do the MSDN sample miss out something for proper registration of extension unit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: May I inquire, @Spark, in the UVC Extension Unit that you created, did you create another module/program/script that can talk with it? I'm asking because I have a RealSense 410 (DS5) camera, and I would like to manipulate its LASER extended control. Alternately, d'you knows of code snippets (preferably in Python) demonstrating how to interact with UVC extension unit controls (preferably using using OpenCV or libv4l2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue in the dll related functions and registration part of UVC Extension sample code provided in MSDN. I have fixed this issue temporarily by modifying dll related code and interface receiving code.

Now I am able to get the interface perfectly at my application and able to communicate through extension unit to UVC USB camera.

Thanks for you kind support [Roman R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/868014/roman-r).

Comment: Hey dude, i see you successfully have developed the extension unit. will you be kind enough to share your implementation, it will be very useful for me as I am stuck right now. you can make a repo at Github. Thanks,

Comment: Hey Sameed, sorry the code is under NDA of my organisation. I'm glad to help you, if you are stuck up at any place. Let the community know what issue you are facing.

Comment: or may be you can add a sample project which builds successfully ?

Comment: At this time it is partially building, ill make improvements
https://github.com/amilamad/uvc_extension_plugin

Answer (score 1):

`CoCreateInstance`'s first parameter has to be COM class identifier, `CLSID`. Chances that `__uuidof(IExtensionUnit)` works out or otherwise expected there are close to zero.

You are supposed to use `CLSID_ExtensionUnit` (from that sample) instead.

UPD. Code snippet to make certain CLSID available to the code.

```c
// Copy your CLSID of interest here in place of XXXXXXXX-YYYY-...
class __declspec(uuid("XXXXXXXX-YYYY-...")) ExtensionUnit; 
CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(ExtensionUnit), ...
```

Comment: But CLSID_ExtensionUnit will not be exported to either interface.h or interface_i.c which was created while building interface.idl.

So I redefined the CLSID as follows in my application locally.

    DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_ExtensionUnit, 0xe4a0682d, 0xda3c, 0x442f, 0xa3, 0xdc, 0x6c, 0x83, 0x41, 0xc3, 0xec, 0x89);

I received unresolved external symbol error which does not looks relevant.

    error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_ExtensionUnit

So I made use of `__uuidof(IExtensionUnit)` as first argument to CoCreateInstance.

Comment: While we register (using regsvr32.exe) this extension unit uvcxuplgn.ax, there should be entry created in registry at following key. `HKCR\CLSID\{e4a0682d-da3c-442f-a3dc-6c8341c3ec89}`. But I dont see any such keys in registry. Since there is not key created, CoCreateInstance fails. Is my understanding right?

Comment: If it is not exported, just copy CLSID declaration into the client app. You have to use correct GUID there anyway.

Comment: Yes, I have done same, but after than I received unresolved external symbol error. I have cross verified GUID of the CLSID that I used in application and extension unit.

Comment: Most likely you did it wrong, check update above to see the easiest way (least chances for mistakes).

Comment: Correct if your Windows is 32-bit. Incorrect otherwise and you need to look into registry under `Wow6432Node`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41544/discussion-between-spark-and-roman-r)